# What can we say about output of Gram–Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $\{x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}\}$ linearly independent vectors and $x_n \in \operatorname{span}\{x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}\}$ and let $\{\hat{x_1}, \dots, \hat{x_{n-1}}, \hat{{x_n}}\}$ be the output of the Gram–Schmidt process.

I have to answer the question: what can we say about $\hat{x_n}$. Of course $\hat{x_n}$ is orthogonal to $\hat{x_1}, \dots \hat{x_{n-1}}$ and $\hat{x_n} \in \operatorname{span}\{x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}\}$ but can we say something more non-trivial?

Comment: Your $\in$ should be a $\notin$ I assume. Otherwise the quetsion is a bit strange.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean $\hat x_n$ and not $\hat n_x$.

Comment: @user38584 yes, right

Comment: @quid no, it is $\in$

Comment: THanks for the clarification. In this case $\hat{x_n}=0$.

Comment: Why? Can you proove it in answer?

Comment: @alex Because $\hat x_n$ is linearly dependent on all other $\hat x_i$ and yet must be orthogonal to all of them.

Comment: @AlexR you forgot your hats.  (Pun intended.)

Comment: @quid I put them on now, thanks :) cf. [picture of proof](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_aDn92f5Nluk/S9nuhBLP9eI/AAAAAAAAABs/q4dVB8SsYRo/s1600/20080524200652!Austin_Lane_Crothers,_photograph_of_head_with_top_hat.jpg) (phunny)

Answer (score -1):

Since we know that $\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}\span(x_i, i=1..n-1) = \span(x_i, i=1..n)$, Gram-Schmidt will produce $\hat x_i$ such that
$$\span(\hat x_i, i=1..n-1) = \span(\hat x_i, i=1..n) \ni \hat x_n$$
and $\langle \hat x_i, \hat x_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker delta). Thus we know that there is some representation
$$\hat x_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \alpha_i \hat x_i$$
and since
$$0 = \langle \hat x_i, \hat x_n \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \alpha_j \langle \hat x_i, \hat x_j \rangle = \alpha_i$$
for all $i=1..n-1$, we have
$$\hat x_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 0 \cdot \hat x_i = 0$$

Comment: Why $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \alpha_j \langle \hat x_i, \hat x_j \rangle = \alpha_i$?

Comment: Why -1? @alex Note that $\langle \hat x_i, \hat x_j \rangle = \cases{1 & $i=j$\\0 & $i\ne j$}$ by definition.